# VB Macro Like Operator

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VB macro.In sheet 3  i have three columns named "Country " "Provinces" and "Risk" 
For  "Provinces",  values present are NB,NS,NF,PE. IN sheet5, i have written a code like

`(val) Like "*[HH,HHJ,qqw,www]" Then

to check if user has provided input like NB or like NB, NS or like PE only then corresponding values from Risk will get displayed. Now with the above code , if user is entering value as "," also results is getting displayed as , is present in the Like statement.

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use VBA `Like` that way.  Try:

```
X = "abc, NB"
If X Like "*NB" Or _
    X Like "*NS" Or _
    X Like "*NF" Or _
    X Like "*PE" Then

    Debug.Print "X is in the Maritimes"
End If
```

If you set `Option Compare Text` at the beginning of your macro, you don't have to `Ucase` the string being tested.

For complex comparisons, you can use Regular Expressions in VBA.  You need to set the appropriate reference.